# What happened to the humans in "Cars" (that is if they ever existed)?

Tags: plot-explanation, cars

In every Disney "Cars" movies there is always some kind of sign of human life. 
However the terrains don't support the fact of humans never existing:

- Human language; writing and signs on billboards vary in languages and surely languages such as English and Japanese are too hard for beings with tires instead of hands
- Door handles on buildings
- Pretty sure the US flag is even shown at a point

In fact the biggest proof of human civilization existing is the cars themselves. If the cars evolved by themselves, then it makes no sense for them to have:

- Doors
- Door handles
- Windows
- Car mirrors
- Their personalities/characteristics which seem to stereotype certain types of humans.

I do understand that the film is meant for children who don't pick up on things like this but I am just curious. I am not looking for theories.

Comment: For that we need a prequel ***Rise of the Planet of the Cars*** ;).

Comment: Related - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79602/if-there-is-a-large-cars-population-how-are-the-cars-brought-into-existance

Comment: I'm pretty sure _Cars_ is what happened after _[Maximum Overdrive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_Overdrive)._

Comment: According to the [Pixar universe theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixar_universe_theory#Cars,_Cars_2,_and_Cars_3_%282110%E2%80%932804%29), the events that precipitated the WALL-E story wiped them out. This is not canon, of course, but some might find it interesting.

Comment: Who's to say the humans went away, or that evolution bound them? It could be a matter of *intelligent design* aka hand of God.  Humans might have been that mechanism, maybe they terraformed this planet to be a car themed amusement park, and the project went bust so the humans went home and the humans went back to Londinium.

Comment: @jpmc26, that "theory" is non canon, though.

Comment: We're shown the history of Route 66 -- a real road in the US -- and find it has always been traveled by/populated with sentient cars, with no humans in sight. Lizzie is a sentient 1923 Model T, dating from soon after the inception of mass-produced cars at the turn of the 20th century. I rather think the evidence in the films suggests there were never any humans.

Comment: I disagree...the evidence cited by the OP indicates that there *were* humans since the USA predates the Model T and door handles  are of no use to cars which don't have *hands*.

Comment: @Paulie_D The cars at various times are shown using their tires or other obviously-not-hands appendages in ways which indicate fine motor skills and the ability to grip; in other words: exactly as if they were hands. And the mirrors in the OP are a totally sensible development: Mater demonstrates that they are actually functional, effectively giving him eyes in the back of his head.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

## There is no **public** canonical explanation.

However...there is a *semi-official* answer...

> The Cars franchise has never offered an official explanation for any of these mysteries. But there is an internal document at Pixar that has never been shared with the public that answers some of these questions, and lays the ground rules for this unusual cinematic universe. It’s called “The World of Cars Owner’s Manual,” and it was written by Jay Ward, the Creative Director of the Cars universe.
>
> <sup>[Screenrant](http://screencrush.com/where-do-pixar-cars-come-from/)</sup>

Ward was asked where do the cars come from and gave this response.

> "If you think about this, we have autonomous car technology coming in right now. It’s getting to the point where you can sit back in the car and it drives itself. Imagine in the near-future when the cars keep getting smarter and smarter and after one day they just go, 'Why do we need human beings anymore? They’re just slowing us down. It’s just extra weight, let’s get rid of them.' But the car takes on the personality of the last person who drove it. Whoa. There you go."

Ward acknowledged that some of them rules are occasionally broken...but

> Number one on the list: “You’ll never see the doors open,” Ward said. “Because the brain and the eyes are in there, we don’t want anything falling out of the side.”

The interview continued...

> Ward did offer  one other possible explanation for the world of Cars.
>
> “[Cars 3 production designer] Jay Shuster did a great drawing a long time ago of a meteor hitting the earth,” Ward said, then mimicking a “Poof!” sound effect. “And all the humans are gone and all of a sudden the cars start rising up and moving around.”

Comment: Fabulous answer, as ever... but the *real* answer is "it doesn't matter, it's a cartoon" ;) Next we'll be questioning if/how/why Scooby Doo talks, or if Muttley's 'saznfrazznrazzn' was *really* swearing :P

Comment: @Tetsujin [I'm so sorry](http://scoobydoo.wikia.com/wiki/Anunnaki_(Scooby-Doo!_Mystery_Incorporated))

Comment: "Why do we need human beings anymore? They’re just slowing us down" - What exactly would the cars mission be? lol

Comment: Hmm, I always thought it was the aftermath of Maximum Overdrive which sorta fits with the last paragraph.

Comment: I don't even see any need for malice, or the Cars taking out the people in this case... People just wound up living in their autonomous cars, for example, and became extinct through attrition.

Comment: See, this is why I never swear at "Ok Google" and other AI variants since in the future, they might say "This guy was good to me. All he did was ask me to sing some songs and tell some jokes... Let's not kill him!" :P

Comment: @Tetsujin I was always preeetty darn sure that Scooby talking was just a figment of Shaggy's stoned imagination. But then again, I'm usually that kind of a romantic. :)

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek Didn't he talk to the others as well? It's been too long since I saw it.

Comment: In the movie "Killdozer", the titular construction vehicle comes to life as an autonomous, malevolent antagonist as a direct result of a meteorite strike.  Had the dozer managed to wipe out the humans on the island, we'd basically have a pulp, 60's b-movie version of Cars. :)

Comment: I always thought they looked like this: http://static.neatorama.com/images/2008-08/inside-pixar-lightning-mcqueen.jpg

Comment: Humans aren't gone...they're symbiotes of the cars. When Ward says "the brain and eyes are in there" that's the vestigial human.

Comment: @1006a: How does that work for the tractors, though?

Comment: The tractors... Yep, I've met plenty of people who would fit quite nicely!

Comment: I don't think the evidence in the OP strongly implies that humans exist/existed in the world of cars, and I don't think those responses from Ward indicate he believes they did either. His answers seem tongue-in-cheek and don't really affirm the premise of the questions.

Comment: Wasn't there a Stephen King movie in the 80s about machines coming to life and trying to murder all humans?  Maybe Cars is set in that universe

Comment: That's covered in the *Maximum Overdrive* comments scattered around.

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek see venture bros for an episode about exactly that.